# How to sort a list of product in CPN Tools(ML)?

Tags: list, sorting, product, sml, ml

In the name of God
I have a colset `colset process_list = list process;` where process stands for this declaration: `colset process = product ratio*ID*wait_time*e_runtime;` and all of used colsets in this colset are of type INT.

Now the problem is that I can't find a way to sort this list. Can anybody help me?   I'll appreciate it.

Comment: What did you try to solve your problem. What have you searched for, if you say you couldn't find a way.

Comment: I've used "fun sort_list(pl) = sort priority.lt (pl);" as a recommend of a friend but it doesn't work

Comment: "Sorry, I'm late", but.. Just answered your question (:

Answer (score 0):

After 4 yrs, for documentation:

```
colset process = product ratio*ID*wait_time*e_runtime;
colset process_list = list process;

fun pass_list ((rt1,id1,wt1,er1), (rt2,id2,wt2,er2)) = id1 < id2;
fun sort_list (pl) = sort pass_list pl;
```